# Using iMac late 2013 as external monitor to HP EliteBook 820 G3 on Windows 10

Tags: display, imac, target-display

Is it at all possible to use my 21.5 inch late 2013 iMac as an external monitor on which I can extend the display of my [HP EliteBook 820 G3](https://store.hp.com/UKStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=Y8Q79EA&opt=ABU&sel=DEF)?

These are the ports that I'm working with on both devices:

[image: 21" 2013 iMac ports]

[image: HP EliteBook 820 G3 Ports]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

In order to use your iMac as a display ([Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)) , you need to connect it via a Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port.  The HP laptop you listed does not have a Thunderbolt port per the technical specifications.

**Software Based Solutions**

- [AirParrot 2](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/). This allows you to "beam" your screen to any supported device
- [SpaceDesk](https://spacedesk.net/).  This software allows you to extend your Windows desktop to another computer or browser over the network.

Comment: So you are saying that a displayport to mini displayport will not work? That cable is readily available, so does the Mac *require* thunderbolt? I always thought that a mini displayport cable would work.

Comment: @SteveChambers -  According to Apple, the 27" in 2009/2010 could use DP or TB.  All others were TB only.

Comment: good to know, thx!

Comment: @Steve Chamber: Here is a [screen shot](https://imgur.com/a/fGCgVra) of the display on a  iMac Late 2013, which is in Target Display Mode. This 2013 iMac is being used as the second monitor connected to Mid 2011 iMac through a Thunderbolt cable. You can see the two Macs are connected through a Thunderbolt bridge. The window in the background is the Desktop of the 2013 iMac.